# Django template not re-rendering on successful AJAX get request

Tags: ajax, django

I have written a very simple ajax code which makes a get request, and it expects django template values as response. So when I try to execute this ajax code, in chrome under network, I can see that the get request was successful and in the preview section under network, I can see the template values that I had expected but the webpage remains same, doesn't get rendered again.

My view:

```
def test(request,id=1):
    return render(request,'test.html',{'num':id,'next':9})
```

My template and ajax code:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<p>{{num}}</p>
<button onclick='test({{next}})'>Test</button>

<script>
function test(next){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/test/'+next,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(){
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Please check this sample image of my problem when I started on '/test/66' , made a click on the button, got the required response, still no change. [image: Sample Request]

Comment: You're mixing server side rendering (DTL) and client side (javascript)

Comment: Since now I have the response that needs to be rendered, what should be my next step to update the page??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing server side rendering (DTL) and client side (javascript). Once django as rendered the template, you're javascript has no access to server side variable as  {{ text }}.

You will have to do :

Template before SSR

```
<div id="content">
  <p>{{num}}</p>
  <button onclick='test({{next}})'>Test</button>
</div>

<script>
    function test(next){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/test/'+next,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
                document.querySelector('#content p').innerHTML(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Template after SSR (something like this, you get the point)

```
<div id="content">
  <p>66</p>
  <button onclick='test(66)'>Test</button>
</div>

<script>
function test(next){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/test/'+next,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            document.querySelector('#content p').innerHTML(data)
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought ajax call would take care of everything, which obviously was wrong . This makes sense.

Comment: No problem!. My pleasure. It can also be confusing when using client side frameworks like : angular and vuejs that use the {{ }} syntax to output variables as well ;) !